# How to enable one button inside a disabled fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to disable all the elements inside Fieldset but enable few buttons inside it. 
[Demo:](http://plnkr.co/edit/VPFFOKTznJT5MGnG32bY?p=preview)

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="true">
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">

    <input type="button" value="See More (Enable this!!) " ng-click="ButtonClicked1()" ng-disabled="false"/>
    Somethingelse: <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="View Details " ng-click="ButtonClicked2()"/> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You want to enable only buttons in fieldset??

Comment: Depending on situations you can use non-input elements like anchor, span etc and style that as your button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jge9z/2042/)

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="form">
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" /><br />
    Date of birth: <input type="text" />

    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="See More (Enable this!!) " onclick="ButtonClicked1()" />
    Somethingelse: <input type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="View Details " onclick="ButtonClicked2()"/> 
</fieldset>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('#form :input').prop('disabled', true);
$("#btn1").prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: But this is not using angular way. However, it works. So probably the question now is how to make it as close as possible to angular. I mean, how you can select all related elements from a controller or directive?

Comment: This a jQuery hack, not a valuable solution

Comment: Here's a horrible hack. If you wrap the input you want to remain enabled in the tags it will still work. No idea how you'd position it though.

Comment: The code in this answer seems to exist exactly the same on this blog:  https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-enable-one-button-inside-a-disabled-fieldset.html

Comment: This doesn't work in chrome. any other viable solutions?

Comment: This answer looses the point of the fieldset. It won’t work if you need some different behavior for disabled fieldset (for example for styling).

Answer (score 12):

I have 3 solutions for you:

## Solution 1: `<details>` and `<summary>`

In your example you should probably use the [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) and [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) elements:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <legend>
    Personalia:
  </legend>

  <label>Name: <input></label>
  <label>Email: <input></label>
  <label>Date of birth: <input></label>

  <label>Somethingelse: <input></label>

  <details>
    <summary>View Details</summary>
    <p>A more detailed description</p>
  </details>
</fieldset>
```

## Solution 2: Put your button inside the `<legend>`

If your are not disclosing a more detailed information, but you want to, say, toggle the disabling of the fieldset, then you can put the toggle button in the [`<legend>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend)

```js
const fieldset = document.querySelector("fieldset");
const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggle-button");

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  fieldset.disabled = !fieldset.disabled;
  toggleButton.textContent = fieldset.disabled ? "Enable" : "Disable";
  toggleButton.setAttribute("aria-pressed", `${!fieldset.disabled}`);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <legend>
    Personalia:
    <button id="toggle-button" aria-pressed="true">
      Enable
    </button>
  </legend>

  <label>Name: <input></label>
  <label>Email: <input></label>
  <label>Date of birth: <input></label>

  <label>Somethingelse: <input></label>
  <button>This may be disabled</button> 
</fieldset>
```

## Solution 3: Use a “fake” button

If your use-case is something entirely different, you can use aria-roles to “fake” a button `role="button"` (see [ARIA button role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role)). Remember to add the necessary accessibility features to make this button clickable for users without display screens or mouse. The important attributes are `role="button"` (for screen readers) and `tabindex="0"` (for keyboard navigation), also remember to add a handler for `keypress` for <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> in case your user doesn’t have a mouse.

```js
const disabledButton = document.querySelector('.disabled-button');
const disabledOutput = document.querySelector('.disabled-output');
const enabledButton = document.querySelector('.enabled-button');
const enabledOutput = document.querySelector('.enabled-output');

function increment(output) {
  const current = Number.parseInt(output.textContent);
  output.textContent = `${current + 1}`;
}

disabledButton.addEventListener('click', () => increment(disabledOutput));
disabledButton.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  if (['Enter', ' '].includes(event.key)) {
    increment(disabledOutput);
  }
});

enabledButton.addEventListener('click', () => increment(enabledOutput));
enabledButton.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  if (['Enter', ' '].includes(event.key)) {
    increment(enabledOutput);
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

[role="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  cursor: default;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <legend>Disabled form elements</legend>

  <label>Input 1<input name="input 1"></label>
  <label>Input 2<input name="input 2"></label>
  
  <button
    class="disabled-button"
    name="disabled-button"
  >
    This is disabled
  </button>

  <i
    class="enabled-button"
    role="button"
    tabindex="0"
  >
    This is enabled
  </i>
</fieldset>

<label>
  Disabled button clicks:
  <output class="disabled-output">0</output>
</label>

<label>
  Enabled button clicks:
  <output class="enabled-output">0</output>
</label>
```

Comment: Putting my `input` inside the `legend` worked for me. My HTML editor complained about putting a bunch of stuff in a `legend` that "shouldn't" be there, but Chrome and Firefox both render it just fine.

Comment: @JacobStamm According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend):

“*The HTML `<legend>` element represents a caption for the content of its parent `<fieldset>`.*”

I think meta controls—such as a checkbox to toggle the fieldset’s disabled state; or action buttons that marginally affect the fieldset’s content—do definitely pass as a caption for the said fieldset. So I think your text editor is giving you an unsound advice. That being said the above example should definitely rather use an `<a>` tag for a link to “show more”.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution 1 - use icons with click event

Use icons instead of buttons and attaching the `click` event to the icons.  This bypasses the disabled fieldset and works like a charm.

```
<fieldset disabled='disabled'>
  <img src='/images/trash-can.png' ng-click='openModal()'/>
</fieldset>
```

and the javascript (using angularjs)

```
$scope.openModal = ()=>{
  // do stuff
};
```

#### Solution 2 - use a Bootstrap-styled span with click event

Bootstrap can style a span to look exactly like a button.  Spans do not use, or inherit, the `disabled` attribute.

```
<fieldset disabled='disabled'>
  <span class="btn btn-default" ng-click='openModal()'>
    Button Text
  </span>
</fieldset>
```

and the javascript (using angularjs)

```
$scope.openModal = ()=>{
  // do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One option: open and close your fieldset around the elements you want to disable. (It would be nice if there was a better way):

```
<fieldset [disabled]="disableForm">
   ....html here that needs to be disabled...
</fieldset>

<button type="button"></button>

<fieldset [disabled]="disabledForm">
   ...more html to disable...
</fieldset>
```