# Data-bind disable attribute doesn't work in a button inside a foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working in a form where I have a table of data and a button to open a modal. I need to set this button to always be enabled; I tried using the code below but without success.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  editarTexto: function(data) {
    alert("msg")
  },
  items: [{}, {}, {}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<fieldset data-bind="disable: true">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-lg-1 ">Texto</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="form-control" data-bind="click: function() { $root.editarTexto($data) }, disable: false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="disable: false">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: By default, a button will be enabled. Something is disabling it, and it has nothing to do with the `disable` binding.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, "This is useful with form elements like input, select, and textarea." (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html) - There is no button element in this list.

Comment: @TSV, you are indeed mistaken. These are just examples. But Roy J's comment seems to be spot on. The responsible part of the code seems to be omitted. A disable-binding is not necessary to make a button always enabled. It should do that by default.

Comment: @TSV a button is a form element like input. The `enable` binding example in the docs uses a button. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

Comment: OP, the code you've posted [works as expected, with all buttons always enabled](https://jsfiddle.net/txduovm7/). Please update your question to include enough code for a [mcve].

Comment: @Jeroen I think now it's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've obscured the actual issue in your title and proze around the code. The code itself however shows that your issue can be paraphrased as:

> How to enable only certain `button`s in a fieldset with the `disabled` attribute?

The repro can thus be much smaller:

```html
<fieldset disabled>
   <input> <!-- should be disabled -->
   <button>x</button> <!-- should be ENabled, but isn't -->
</fieldset>
```

And the answer is: you can't. The only solution is to *not* disable the `fieldset` and set all descendant elements `disabled` except the buttons.

---

For reference, you can see from [the `enable`/`disable` binding source file](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/enableDisable.js) that it doesn't do anything besides setting the `disabled` attribute on the element in question.

---

For reference, see the MDN entry about [`fieldset` `disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Attributes):

> If this Boolean attribute is set, the form controls that are its descendants, except descendants of its first optional  element, are disabled, i.e., not editable. They won't receive any browsing events, like mouse clicks or focus-related ones. Often browsers display such controls as gray.

---

For reference, see also [the AngularJS version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25446225/419956).

Comment: I feel like using the `form` attribute, pointing to a form that isn’t disabled, should keep my button enabled. Or better yet, buttons with `type="button"`. But that isn’t the case. You can keep an enabled “button” though by using the ARIA `role="button"`. See an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55155649/2444959

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmlfieldsetelement) you can put your button inside the `<legend>`.

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <legend>
    Legend
    <!-- This is ENABLED -->
    <button onclick="console.log('click')">Enabled</button>
  </legend>
  <input> <!-- this is disabled -->
  <button>disabled</button> <!-- this is disabled -->
</fieldset>
```