# Enable button in disabled fieldset with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a fieldset with many input fields, combos and buttons. To edit something, you have to activate an edit mode.

Is it possible to enable one button in this disabled fieldset without using multiple fieldsets? It would be nice to use the lookup buttons even if the edit mode is not activated.

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="ctrl.condition">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">{{ 'Generally' | i18n}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        ...
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px">
                    <dn-input text="some text" typ="number" modell="ctrl.value"></dn-input>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-right: 0px">
                    <!-- This part should be enabled -->
                    <dn-eingabe text="another text">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.func()">...</button>
                    </dn-eingabe>
                    <!-- -->
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: If your design allows for the input you need enabled to be [absolutely positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Absolute_positioning), then putting it in the `legend` will work. Got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55155649/4028303).