# Enable html button when FieldSet is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, fieldset

I have a fieldset tag that I am setting the property disabled on if a particular URL variable exist:

```
<fieldset class="fieldsetGeneralSettings" <cfif #url.read_only# eq 'yes'>disabled="disabled"</cfif> >
</fieldset>
```

All elements of the fieldset are disabled when I set that property to disabled, however I have an HTML button inside that fieldset that I want to force to be enabled. I tried to force it using the following javascript but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<button id="followup_detail_button" class="TicketButton" onclick="followupButtonDetailsClick(event);"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"> </i> <font color="red">Follow-up Request</font></button>
                     
<button id="followup_button" class="TicketButton" onclick="followupButtonClick(event);"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"> </i> Follow-up Request</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("Trying to enable the button");
        $("##followup_detail_button").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("##followup_button").removeAttr('disabled');
    })
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the suggestion over here  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55155649/1636917